# &amp; instead of & in Jqxgrid

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid

i have a problem with jqxgrid"s displaying data `&amp;` instead of `&` , i have grid of about 7 columns , in that 3 columns have these special character issue ,the data is coming from the Json by using ajax calls.
please advise me some suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace &amp; by & symbol by using regular expression.
Below code will replace all &amp; with &

Code:

```
data.replace(/&amp;/g,"&");
```

Comment: @Wooble : It will find all &amp and replace with &. I given only for &amp; string.

Comment: @wooble string.replace will only replace the first instance so you do actually need the regex in order to pass the /g flag.  yes it is silly but javascript is often silly

Comment: @Wooble - Doesn't work in all browsers, at least not IE.  MDN says this: "The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace.

Comment: Well, learn something new that's awful about JS being implemented inconsistently every day, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

another possible reason is the usage of old version of [http://www.jqwidgets.com](http://www.jqwidgets.com/)